# SLIM Framework - Different result on $app->urlFor() and $app->router()->urlFor()

Tags: php, twig, slim

I'm having problem with `$app->urlFor()`.
I have **blog** named route. Everytime I use `$app->urlFor('blog')` to create a link, the function is always returning localhost:8000/**index.php**/blog instead of **localhost:8000/blog**.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Are you on `localhost:8000` or `localhost:8000/index.php`?

Comment: I accessed localhost:8000/blog just fine.

I looked into urlFor() functions and got this:
`return $this->request->getRootUri() . $this->router->urlFor($name, $params);`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure your webserver to use pretty URLs:

http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-URL-Rewriting

Comment: Thanks for your response..I'm using php built-in server to run the application. I have followed the URL Rewriting and folder structure. I can access the url via **localhost:8000/blog**, But when I generate the named url with `$app->urlFor('blog')` it's still resulting **localhost:8000/index.php/blog** which brings me to 404 page..